# Access IBM Q processors from MatLab

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, matlab

Qiskit allows a user to directly access IBM Q quantum processors (both real ones and simulator). Each user is given a *personal code* which is entered into source code and serves as a login to the IBM Q platform.

**My question is:** Is there a similar possibility in MatLab? In other words, is there any module/code in MatLab allowing to access IBM Q processors?

Comment: you can try to create QASM files from MatLab...

Comment: @draks... I am a little bit lost, do you mean to program a script generating QASM files? But how to download results from IBM Q. I am afraid that this cannot be fully automatic and some user influence is needed.

Comment: Oh yeah true, although the result might just be a vector. The question also is what/how you would like to compose something in MatLab? Do you want to give matrices (which would be nice)?

Comment: @draks...I would like to use MatLab for controlling a work with quantum computer like in Qiskit, i.e. to feed data through MTL script, run an quantum algorithm on IBM Q then take the results and post-process them.

Comment: ok but what will be in your MTL script? A sequence of local rotations, CNOTs and so on? Or just some parameters like rotation angles that are applied at certain local operations, that are specified somewhere else (like a QASM file). Reading results back and do post processing sound like a good idea. user47787's I/F should do that...

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do what I want through Python code connected with MatLab. I was just curious if is there any direct way, i.e. if MatLab has a toolkit for quantum computers programing.

Comment: Don't of any. Put 500 bounty for writing the matlab addon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no MatLab library for the IBM quantum experience. It may be possible to call [Qiskit from Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-python.html)